# Assigning selectors to variables to call them depending on the type of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, css-selectors

Thats the best description I could think of. I normally do not post, but I honestly cannot figure this out.

Still in jquery learning mode, and basically what I want to accomplish is that depending on the type of button that is submitted, the script assigns variables to div's on the page. What I am making is a admin side of a user script to allow them to update that particular div that appears on the page.

When I put in the actual selectors, the script works.

When the page loads, it will take the field of the database that corresponds with the  and load it. Once they push the update button, a new div will appear. The admin inputs his new data (the new information he wants to display) and it updates the mysql table, then pulls it back in through jquery's ajax.

Sorry for the long explanation. Like I said, I've never really posted, just always liked figuring it out on my own.
php page

```
<?php //
if(isLoggedIn())
{
echo '<button id="adultClassButton">Edit Class Information</button>';
}
?>
<div class="class" id="adultClass"><?php
$row = checkPost('adult');
echo $row['info'];
?>
</div>

<?php


echo '<div id="adultClassInput">
  <textarea rows="2" cols="80" id="adultClassUpdate"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" id="className" name="adult"/>
  <button id="adult">Save the Updated Class Info</button></div>';

?>
```

javascript (jquery) file

```
$(".button").click(function(){
var button = $(this).attr('id');
if (button == 'adult'){

    var classDiv = $("#adultClass");
    var className = $("#className");
    var classDesc = $("#adultClassUpdate").val();
    var classUpdateDiv = $("#adultClassInput");
    postData(classDiv, className, classDesc, classUpdateDiv);
}
});

function postData(classDiv, className, classDesc, classUpdateDiv){
$.ajax({
url: 'insert.php',
type: 'POST',
data: "name="+ className+ "& info="+ classDesc,
success:function(data){
$("#" + classDiv).html(data);
}
})
$("#" + classDesc).val('');
$("#" + classUpdateDiv).hide();
}
```

Like I said, if I have normal selectors in the function, it works as intended. But as of right now, I'm just stumped as to whats wrong.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this:

```
function postData(classDiv, className, classDesc, classUpdateDiv){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"name": className.val(), "info": classDesc}
    success:function(data){
      classDiv.html(data);
    }
  })
  $("#"+classDesc).val('');
  classUpdateDiv.hide();
}
```

because you already passed jquery objects (**not strings**) to your function, except for `classDesc`.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
I implemented both, which make sense, however when the button is pressed it still does not update the database. I think the error is in the click event, I just cannot figure out where. As it stands I have an IF statement to see if the button's value attribute = adult (adult dog training), but if I can get this working I would like to switch it to a switch statement (Pun intended)

Comment: .button selector won't match anything because there is no button with the class "button".

Comment: @Jonathan: You're welcome. As Anurag says, you should do `$("#adult").click` instead  of `$(".button").click`, that's why the button isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

classDiv is a jquery object not the ID of the element. So when you use this

```
$("#" + classDiv).html(data);
```

That's not working as expected.

Try

```
classDiv.html(data);
```